# Recovering deleted VM from disabling compute engine

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, billing

Due to reasons, my billing account went into the red and I was not in good standing. Since I failed to reopen my account in time for reasons, Google Cloud disabled billing on my account and, as of a few weeks ago, disabled my Compute Engine entirely. I got a bee in my bonnet and decided to reopen my account today, only to find that both VMs were deleted, along with the disks and snapshots of said disks. My VPC configurations and reserved static IP addresses were also wiped, meaning that essentially my entire project was wiped. The only thing that remains is my cloud console shell environment.

Is there any way to recover the disks the VMs resided on? The VMs and IP addresses are one thing, but I would ***really*** hate to have all that data wiped in one go.

Comment: No, you cannot recover the data from deleted resources.

Answer (score 1):

If billing becomes disabled on your projects, all billable Google Cloud services in the affected projects are shut down.

As stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#restoring_a_project)

> You can recover most resources if you restore a project within the
> 30-day period. Some services have delays in restoring and you might
> need to wait some time for services to be restored.

Do note that some resources are deleted earlier within the 30-day period and are not recoverable.

However, At the end of the 30-day period, the project and all of its resources are deleted and cannot be recovered even if the Billing account is reestablished.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I've been over that 30 day threshold, but I suppose it doesn't hurt to grasp a few more straws. My project was never deleted to begin with, but the services were disabled. I never got an email saying my services would be outright deleted, only disabled. But I still don't see any of my compute engine resources. Would I just have to wait a few days for my VMs and everything to reappear? Or am I shit out of luck?

Comment: @guninvalid - deleted resources do not reappear.